# Slick: Update of field on SQLServer/jtds

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to update a field with Slick 2.0 and connected to a SQL Server via jtds driver

Table:

```
object UtilisateurSchema {

    class UtilisateurId(val value: Long) extends MappedTo[Long]

    case class Utilisateur(id: Option[UtilisateurId], nom: String, prenom: String)

    class Utilisateurs(tag: Tag) extends Table[Utilisateur](tag, "UTILISATEUR") {
        def id = column[UtilisateurId]("UTL_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        def nom = column[String]("UTL_NOM")
        def prenom = column[String]("UTL_PRENOM")

        // Defaut projection
        def * = (id.?, nom, prenom) <>(Utilisateur.tupled, Utilisateur.unapply _)

    }
    val utilisateurs = TableQuery[Utilisateurs]
}
```

I have a user in my table whose id is `1331`.

The code below gives me an exception:

```
val user = utilisateurs filter (  _.id === new UtilisateurId(1331L))
println(user first)
val newUser = user first() copy( nom = "Foo")
println(newUser)
user update(newUser)
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Impossible de mettre à jour la colonne identité 'UTL_ID'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:584)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:546)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:506)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInvokerComponent$UpdateInvoker$$anonfun$update$1.apply(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:282)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInvokerComponent$UpdateInvoker$$anonfun$update$1.apply(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:277)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:161)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:297)
    at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInvokerComponent$UpdateInvoker.update(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:277)
    at com.sqlconnect.SqlPlayground$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SqlPlayground.scala:100)
    at com.sqlconnect.SqlPlayground$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SqlPlayground.scala:37)
    at scala.slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.withSession(DatabaseComponent.scala:31)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$4.withSession(JdbcBackend.scala:61)
    at com.sqlconnect.SqlPlayground$.main(SqlPlayground.scala:36)
    at com.sqlconnect.SqlPlayground.main(SqlPlayground.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

`Impossible de mettre à jour la colonne identité 'UTL_ID'` means :

```
Impossible to update identity column 'UTL_ID'
```

I have done some tests at home connecting to a MySQL driver and the above way to update works

On the other hand, using the below code works for MSSQL + jtds:

```
val nom = for ( u <- utilisateurs if u.id === new UtilisateurId(1331L)) yield u.nom
nom.update("Foo")
```

Can anyone explain what I m doing wrong in the 1st case? or is that a bug?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no relation to your code <del>or driver</del>; SQL server doesn't allow simply editing `IDENTITY` columns; you have to use [identity insert mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Even this has drawbacks: you can only turn on identity insert on one table in a session at a time.

I haven't used slick with SQL Server, but if it isn't smart enough to leave primary keys alone, you may have to create your own method for update.

Also note that slick requires commercial license for use with SQL Server, <del>whatever that may mean</del>. A proper SQL Server support is offered as part of a [closed-source package](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/extensions.html)

Comment: Ok but how do Hibernate do then to update an entity (we use hibernate with Java)? I do a get(id), it retrieves an object with an id, i change a field and update. Maybe Slick uses another strategy.

Comment: I am aware of the commercial license. I just uses it at work as I have data in my test database so that I can play with it, but we dont use Scala at work.

Comment: Hibernate, Slick, or whatever - they all generate SQL queries to interact with database. My guess is that Slick generates something like `update <table> set [<field>=<value> pairs for all columns] where <id>=someId`. This will work for some databases, but not for SQL server with identity `id` - a proper way would be to update all columns except for `id`. But you can still write proper queries yourself - after all, Slick is no ORM.

Comment: Slick works with tuples, and you specify how exactly to convert case classes into tuples and back (`tupled` / `unapply`). It may be really not smart enough to ignore some of the fields by itself.

Comment: Slick is like SQL in that regard. user.update(...) is a query "UPDATE user SET ..." no where part unless you user.filter(...).update(...). It makes a lot of sense when you realize what you put left of update is just a query. Unified api for selects and updates so to speak. If you provide the whole object to update it will try to update every column. But you can't update the id. For convenience, Slick 2 ignores the id for inserts by default and should probably do the same for updates. We have a ticket for it. https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/601